# Highlight image when checkbox is checked, and when clicking on the image

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Not working

```
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="check-with-label" />
   <label for="check" class="label-for-check">My Label
   <img class="product-add-image-preview" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/417MwhxcFKL._SY300_.jpg" />
   </label>
</div>
```

This works

```
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="check-with-label" />
   <label for="check" class="label-for-check">My Label </label>
   <img class="product-add-image-preview" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/417MwhxcFKL._SY300_.jpg" />
</div>
```

I need the image in the label so that when I select the image, the checkbox is checked. But I can't seem to make the CSS work when I have the image in label.

http://jsfiddle.net/4QV3s/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're trying to access the image, but you forgot about the label. Also, you don't want to use ~, you want to use + so it will access the following, and only the following label. Replace the + with the ~ again, and you'll see what I mean.

```
.check-with-label:checked + label > .product-add-image-preview {
    border:10px solid yellow;
    padding:0; /* To keep things from moving */
}
```

Here's an updated fiddle. I added a second image so you could see them work independently of each other: http://jsfiddle.net/4QV3s/1/